# How is Neural Networks Implemented in OpenCv?

Tags: neural-network, face-recognition

I want to implement Face Recognition using Neural Networks in OpenCv in visual studio.
I know that implementing Neural Networks in Matlab is quite easy but i have almost complemented my face recognition project in Visual Studio.I have seen OpenCv MLP library functions but i dont understand how to use them.Some example codes would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? Have you researched anything yourself?

Comment: I have researched a lot.I understand the background.But i am unable to find some codes for visual studio.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. What language are you trying to use?

Comment: OpenCv 2.3 is in C++ So c/C++ only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at OpenCV's [tutorials page](http://opencv.itseez.com/), especially the [machine learning tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/ml/table_of_content_ml/table_of_content_ml.html).

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, there are only two tutorials discussing support vector machines on that page.

Another place you can look is the [Emgu CV wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Emgu CV is a .NET wrapper over OpenCV. That means that you can use the OpenCV library in C# or other .NET languages. They have a section that contains [machine learning examples](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial#Machine_Learning_Examples). The examples are written in C#, but they use the same functions in the C++ OpenCV. Therefore, you can easily translate them to C++.